# fabric-sdk-node fails to retrieve the context of an existing user

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I've got some problems while calling the function `<async> getUserContext(name, checkPersistence)`, so far I know it fails only when I try to get the context of an existing user, but it does work with non existing users.

The code I use to create the client object and call the function is as follows:

```
const config = '-connection-profile-path';
        const client = hfc.loadFromConfig(hfc.getConfigSetting(`network${config}`));
        client.loadFromConfig(hfc.getConfigSetting(`${this.orgId}${config}`));
        await client.initCredentialStores();
        const admin = await client.getUserContext('admin', true);
```

And the error is:

> [2019-10-04 11:41:38.701] [ERROR] utils/registerUser - TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined

which, as far as I know, makes no sense. The only solution I`ve found is to check if the certificates are up to date, that is deleting it and let runApp.sh & setupAPIs.sh (I'm using the balance-transfer example from **hyperledger/fabric-samples**) create the folder again with all those certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the only problem was that the users inside the docker container I was using were desynced with the ones in the State Store. So if you are using docker make sure to keep the users synchronized.